# Symfony and FineUploader delete file

Tags: php, symfony, fine-uploader

I have problem with file delete from uploaded folder with this uploader..

```
var myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#uploader')[0],
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: '{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('attachment') }}',

        },

        deleteFile:{
            enabled: true,  method: 'DELETE', endpoint:'/var/www/integra/app/../vendor/fineuploader/php-tradional-server/endpoint.php'
        },
```

I've try endpoint: `oneup_uploader_endpoint('attachment')`, but it doesn't work with upload at all. 
I have install to vendor php-tradional-server.

How can I delete uploaded file?

Comment: with ajax i can't delete too , because fineUploader rename file name... I don't know that to do...

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What errors are you seeing? How do you reproduce the issue? Based on your code, it looks like you may not even be running an HTTP/PHP server. You need an HTTP server in order to support HTTP requests.

Comment: No route found for "DELETE /var/www/integra/vendor/fineuploader/php-tradional-server/endpoint.php/600863ec-b470-4be0-87ec-a87b9032c784" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/billing/client/2")  I do not understand how to make the server part to delete a file from a directory

Comment: I did want delete from folder this file with my method with ajax , but fineUploader after uploader rename file name , but when i try get file name , it return me original file name , how need to do delete , i read documentation and stackoverflow questions but me never not help

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the path for delete requests is incorrect. You will need to take s closer look at your server code to determine the correct path.

Also, Fine Uploader identifies files using a unique ID. This is preferred since multiple files can share the same name. You should maintain a map of Fine Uploader UUIDs to files server side in a database. If you prefer, you can ask Fine Uploader to send addition headers or request parameters of your choosing. This is mentioned on the delete file feature page at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/delete.html.